# Global delegate to subscribe to

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I have Multiple class that need  to subscribe to a delegate. 
How is that possible? If I do declare delegate in my mainForm is that well coded?

Example code:

```
internal delegate void DEL_SetSingleVal(Single value);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Single Data;
    ClasswithDel ClassDelegate;
    TryToAccess AccessDelegate;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ClassDelegate = new ClasswithDel();
        AccessDelegate = new TryToAccess();
        ClassDelegate.SetValCbk += new DEL_SetSingleVal(SetValCbkFn);
        ClassDelegate.SetValCbk += new DEL_SetSingleVal(AccessDelegate.SetValCbkObj2Fn);
    }
    internal void SetValCbkFn(Single value)
    {
        Data = value;
    }
    private void SetValueLabel(String value)
    {
        label1.Text = value;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClassDelegate.SetValue(Convert.ToSingle(textBox1.Text));
    }
}
public class TryToAccess
{
    private Single Data2;
    internal void SetValCbkObj2Fn(Single value)
    {
        Data2 = value;//value come from From1
    }
}
public class ClasswithDel
{
    internal DEL_SetSingleVal SetValCbk;
    public void SetValue(Single valuesent)//value to dispatch to Form1 and TryToAccess
    {
        SetValCbk(valuesent);
    }
}
```

Is this looking good? Thanks for help!

Comment: It's not in the `Form1` class. It's just in `Form1.cs` file. It's in the same namespace which `Form1` is in.

Comment: Normally you have to create new file for each `class`. Many (including me) are using solution explorer and not class browser to navigate solution, then it's easier with `class = file` correspondence.

Comment: I do the same, I don't understand what you want to say sorry. I have one class one file normally (unless it is a small class) here it is for the example that I wrote it like this.